# Rust: How to match an enum with struct and getting the enum value on match

Tags: rust, struct, enums, pattern-matching

The scenario is an enum that has many structs. How can Rust match which enum is used and call the appropriate function with the enum struct value?

Here is a small reconstitution of the scenario:

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
pub enum MyEnum {
    ChoiceA(DetailA),
    ChoiceB(DetailB),
}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct DetailA {
    pub message: String,
}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct DetailB {
    pub password: String,
    pub value: u8,
}

pub fn handleChoiceA(input:DetailA){
    println!("Choice A {}", input.message);
}
pub fn handleChoiceB(input:DetailB){
    println!("Choice B {}", input.password);
}

fn main() {
    let value = MyEnum::ChoiceA({
        DetailA {
            message: "Test".to_string()
        }
    });
    
    match value {
        MyEnum::ChoiceA(_) => { // <---- issue
            handleChoiceA(_);   // <---- issue
        }
        MyEnum::ChoiceB(_) => {
            handleChoiceB(_);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a link to the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2547aafa31d4b3ce73c726aaab182e2d)

One tentative was to try to match using the Rust destruction pattern, but I am losing the value to pass to the function `MyEnum::ChoiceA({..})`, but then I have nothing to pass to `handleChoiceA(????)`.

What is the correct pattern to match and access the struct value of the enum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
pub enum MyEnum {
    ChoiceA(DetailA),
    ChoiceB(DetailB),
}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct DetailA {
    pub message: String,
}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct DetailB {
    pub password: String,
    pub value: u8,
}

pub fn handleChoiceA(input: DetailA) {
    println!("Choice A {}", input.message);
}
pub fn handleChoiceB(input: DetailB) {
    println!("Choice B {}", input.password);
}

fn main() {
    let value = MyEnum::ChoiceA({
        DetailA {
            message: "Test".to_string(),
        }
    });

    match value {
        MyEnum::ChoiceA(a) => {
            handleChoiceA(a);
        }
        MyEnum::ChoiceB(b) => {
            handleChoiceB(b);
        }
    }
}
```

```
Choice A Test
```

Comment: Thank you @Finomnis, I didn't realize that `_` was a special character ‍♂️

Comment: Yah, `_` means 'ignore whatever is at that position'. ;)